# matplotlibで作成したプロット結果をeps形式でファイルに保存できない

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = np.array([8,8**2,8**3,8**4,8**5,8**6])
y = np.array([6.246, 26.0417, 97.0874, 340.909, 1166.67, 3870.97])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig("test.eps")
```

上記のコードで、test.pngだと保存してくれるのですが、拡張子をepsに変更すると保存されず、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
<ipython-input-23-eb636dd8cfff> in <module>
      4 y = np.array([6.246, 26.0417, 97.0874, 340.909, 1166.67, 3870.97])
      5 plt.plot(x,y)
----> 6 plt.savefig("test.eps")

C:\JuliaPkg\conda\3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    687 def savefig(*args, **kwargs):
    688     fig = gcf()
--> 689     res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    690     fig.canvas.draw_idle()   # need this if 'transparent=True' to reset colors
    691     return res

C:\JuliaPkg\conda\3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in savefig(self, fname, frameon, transparent, **kwargs)
   2092             self.set_frameon(frameon)
   2093 
-> 2094         self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
   2095 
   2096         if frameon:

C:\JuliaPkg\conda\3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
   2073                     orientation=orientation,
   2074                     bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
-> 2075                     **kwargs)
   2076             finally:
   2077                 if bbox_inches and restore_bbox:

C:\JuliaPkg\conda\3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py in print_eps(self, outfile, *args, **kwargs)
    919 
    920     def print_eps(self, outfile, *args, **kwargs):
--> 921         return self._print_ps(outfile, 'eps', *args, **kwargs)
    922 
    923     def _print_ps(self, outfile, format, *args,

C:\JuliaPkg\conda\3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py in _print_ps(self, outfile, format, papertype, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, *args, **kwargs)
    944             self._print_figure_tex(outfile, format, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor,
    945                                    orientation, isLandscape, papertype,
--> 946                                    **kwargs)
    947         else:
    948             self._print_figure(outfile, format, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor,

C:\JuliaPkg\conda\3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py in _print_figure_tex(self, outfile, format, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, isLandscape, papertype, metadata, dryrun, bbox_inches_restore, **kwargs)
   1334                     or rcParams['text.usetex']):
   1335                 gs_distill(tmpfile, isEPSF, ptype=papertype, bbox=bbox,
-> 1336                            rotated=psfrag_rotated)
   1337             elif rcParams['ps.usedistiller'] == 'xpdf':
   1338                 xpdf_distill(tmpfile, isEPSF, ptype=papertype, bbox=bbox,

C:\JuliaPkg\conda\3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py in gs_distill(tmpfile, eps, ptype, bbox, rotated)
   1469 
   1470     gs_exe = ps_backend_helper.gs_exe
-> 1471     if ps_backend_helper.supports_ps2write: # gs version >= 9
   1472         device_name = "ps2write"
   1473     else:

C:\JuliaPkg\conda\3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py in supports_ps2write(self)
     92         True if the installed ghostscript supports ps2write device.
     93         """
---> 94         return self.gs_version[0] >= 9
     95 
     96 ps_backend_helper = PsBackendHelper()

C:\JuliaPkg\conda\3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py in gs_version(self)
     76 
     77         s = subprocess.Popen(
---> 78             [self.gs_exe, "--version"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
     79         pipe, stderr = s.communicate()
     80         ver = pipe.decode('ascii')

C:\JuliaPkg\conda\3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
    707                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    708                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 709                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    710         except:
    711             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

C:\JuliaPkg\conda\3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
    995                                          env,
    996                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
--> 997                                          startupinfo)
    998             finally:
    999                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] 指定されたファイルが見つかりません。
```

他のサイトで「拡張子を変えればよいだけ」と書いてありましたが、うまくいかず、エラーメッセージの内容がよく解読できないので、お力添え頂きたく質問しました。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: EPSの指定は出来ているものの、[matplotlib.backends.backend_ps](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/backends/backend_ps.html) で呼んでいる `self.gs_exe` が存在しないのが原因ですかね？

Comment: pip install backend_ps.py をするということですか？

Comment: いいえ、 `backend_ps` は `matplotlib` の中身なので不要です。自分の環境でも再現性があり、かつ検索してみても同様の事例が見つからなかったので、しばらく待っても回答が得られない場合matplotlib側の公式にサポートを求めるのが適切かもしれません。

Comment: わかりました、matplotlibが3.0.2であったので、どうやら使えなかったみたいです。最新バージョン3.0.3にしたらうまくいきました。

Answer (score 1):

コマンドプロンプトからpip installとガチャガチャやっていたら、pipをアップグレードしてくれと注意が来たので、アップグレードし、jupyterで同様に

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
y = np.array([6.246, 26.0417, 97.0874, 340.909, 1166.67, 3870.97])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig("test.eps")
```

と行ったところ、epsファイルが生成されました。
どうやら最新のバージョンにする必要があったみたいです。解決しました。

Comment: 参考までに、現在と過去（問題が起きていた状態）のバージョンを追記していただけませんか？

Comment: ターミナルコマンド消してしまったので、どういう風に過去のバージョンを見ればよいのでしょうか。。ただ更新したmatplotlibのverは19.0.3です

Comment: pip 19.0.3です。。。

Comment: 現在2019.5月時点でmatplotlib3.0.3である必要がありました。